# Local indexing of rich text files

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, local-storage, offline-caching

I am trying to create a local index for my notes which comprises mainly of markdown files, text files, codes in python, javascript and dart.
I came across Solr and Elasticsearch.
But the main differences are focused around online use and distributedness.
Which can be a better choice if i need a good integrarion with javascript through electronjs?

Keeping in mind that the files are on local storage and there is not much focus on distributedness but on integration with javascript frontend and efficiency on local system.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch is more popular among newer developers due to its ease of use. But if you are already used to working with Solr, stay with it because there is no specific advantage of migrating to Elasticsearch.

I believe for your use case either of them would work.

However, If you need it to handle analytical queries in addition to searching text, Elasticsearch is the better choice

 In terms of popularity, a larger community, documentations I would say elasticsearch is the winner, You can look at the below google trends

[image]

Comment: I digged a little deeper and found whoosh and pylucene. Would you recommemd either of these over elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solr along with Apache Tika.
Apache Tika help in extracting the content/Text of different file system.

Using the above the you can index the metadata of the files and content of the files to the Apache solr.

You get admin tool for the analysis of the index and the fields to determine if you able to achieve the desired result.